# What is the word for letters that do not ascend above the midline / uniform height? (i.e. aceuomnwxz, not btlj)

Tags: meaning, questions

I found the word for the part of letters that rise above the midline (ascender: The part of a lowercase letter that rises above the main body of the letter (as in b, d, h). The part that extends above the x-height of a font.), but I seem to be unable to find a word that denotes the letters that do not ascend (or descend) above the "x-height."

A word that categorizes the letters "weruoaszxcvnm" but not "qtyipdfghjklb".

Also, is there a word for words composed solely of these letters? (e.g. *erroneous*). I was trying to find the longest such word of letters with uniform height.

Comment: I believe the 'i' should be in the other category as well.

Comment: @wythagoras You're right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you could call them **x-height letters**. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-height):

> Lowercase letters whose total height is greater than the x-height
>   either have descenders which extend below the baseline, such as y, g,
>   q, and p, or have ascenders which extend above the x-height, such as
>   l, k, b, and d.

We can infer that letters which do not have descenders or ascenders are (approximately) x-height. (If you want to be picky, an "x" is not always the exact same height as an "s," but it's generally close enough.)

Which letters have ascenders and descenders may depend on the typeface or script variant that is being used. But in normal modern Latin fonts, I believe the set of letters with neither ascenders nor descenders is consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Running the string **weruoaszxcvnm** past a Scrabble word generator produces the nine-letter word **cavernous**.

I imagine there are longer technical words.

Editing later to add: my previous answer assumed that each letter could be used only once. If you can use any of these letters any number of times the problem gets out of hand. Doubling up the string twice and then having a stab at adding in a few more of what I judged "useful" ones turned up **curvaceousness** at 14 letters. I'd also like to point out that **necromancer** is the longest word if every letter is only allowed twice because, come on, *necromancer*, dude.

Editing yet again because we missed "i": In this case the longest word with only one use of each letter is **microwaves** at 10, allowing them twice gets you a tie at 13 with **unceremonious** and **anniversaries**. Chucking in one more letter (because that's the longest string I could handle) got me up to 15 with **overanxiousness**, **carnivorousness**, and the smacks-of-cheating **unveraciousness**.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you include "i"?  The dot extends above the x-height, which I think should disqualify it.  And I would like to allow the x-height letters to be used multiple times, and see what words, phrases, sentences, poems and stories we can come up with!  We could use the same limits on punctuation, which would mean we could use . : - = + but not ! ( ) [ ] ? " , ; / ' right?

Comment: This is not really an answer. It is a comment agianst other posts.